# How do I make the A-Frame player/camera collide with objects (make it not go through it)

Tags: html, aframe, webvr

I am making an A-Frame non-VR desktop WASD game. I have been experimenting with A-Frame, A-Frame extras, and A-Frame Physics Extras, but I can't seem to figure out how I can make the camera/player not walk through objects (like planes or boxes).

I have already tried dynamic-body and static-body, but either don't work in my experiences using them. I do not know if I am using them correctly either.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.